# No express view engine

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, express

In express, you set the view engine like this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

In my application, I do not need a view engine. All output is json, without any templates. I have uninstalled jade.

Which value do I set for the view engine if I do not want to use one?

Comment: Just remove `app.set('view engine', 'jade')` from your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't use `res.view()` and only stick with `res.json()` you shouldn't have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set a value for that. You can use `res.json({ message: 'Successful' });` to send the response as a json where `{ message: 'Successful' }` is the json that you want to send.